# Sending an email multiple times with smtplib in Python

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

I have written the following code to send an email that simply sends "test" to a specified email address.

```
 import smtplib
        sentFrom = "my email" 
        to = input("Enter email:  ")
        #numberEmails = raw_input ("Enter number of emails to send")
        messageText = "test"

        msg = "From: %s\n To: %s\n\n%s" % (sentFrom, to, messageText)

        username = str("my email")  
        password = str("my password")  

        try :
            server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.login(username,password)
            server.sendmail(sentFrom, to, msg)
            server.quit()    
            print (" Email has sent")
        except :
        print("email NOT sent")
```

When I try to send more emails than 1, for example:

```
 5*server.sendmail(sentFrom, to, msg)
```

Only one email sends, then I get the error "email NOT sent." I do not get an "email has sent" after the first email sends, only an "email NOT sent" print after the first. How can I fix this issue? I want to eventually have an input() so I can enter in the number of emails to send, and the program sends the number of emails entered into the input. I put how I think this would look as a comment at the top. Can I just multiply the server.sendmail command by the numberEmails command?

This is my first day using Python so go easy on me pls. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply this.

Multiplications can only be done with numbers, `server.sendmail(sentFrom, to, msg)` does not result in a number.

You're going to have to loop through the amount needed.

So as an example, this prints "hello world" five times:

```
def test():
    print "hello world"

numberEmails = 5

for _ in range(numberEmails):
    test()
```

Off course you have to parse your numberEmails to int if it's not an integer.

Eventually you have to loop through this entire block 5 times

```
try :
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username,password)
        server.sendmail(sentFrom, to, msg)
        server.quit()    
        print (" Email has sent")
    except :
    print("email NOT sent")
```

Comment: I ended up using a while loop, thanks for the well-written response.